# How to export wordpress post to json

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I want to export a page of wordpress data field are eventtitle, description, date, posted date. my requirement is export as json only eventTitle and Description.

Comment: You should connect to the database, build the query and have php deliver you the json_encoded result.

Comment: Thanks! How to build query ??

Comment: the whole idea of stack overflow is that you ask when you can't figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing and using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-content-importer/
(edit due to comment below, now listed another plugin)

Comment: This plugin is now closed due to security reasons.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, listed another plugin and removed the one with security issues.

Comment: This plugin is called importer, not exporter, and the description doesn't seem to suit OP's needs

Answer (score 1):

Under OSX You can use an application called SequelPro which is able to export any selection of your database to JSON.

You can also try NocoDB which is a sort of airtable open source alternative. It is able to JSON export your SQL data.